# file.exists() is returning false in JSR223 Assertion.When hit file path in windows explorer then file is getting open

Tags: jmeter

```
String file = vars.get("downloadedFileName");
log.info("file name is " + file);
String path= "C:\\Users\\abhishek\\Desktop\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-3.3\\bin\\";
String filePath = path+file+".pdf";
//System.out.println("file address is " + file);
log.info("file address is " + filePath);

File file1 = new File(filePath);
    //exists = file.exists();
    log.info("File existance result"+file1.exists());
    if (file1.exists())  
    {
      log.info("file exists, and it is a file");
    }else{
log.info("file does not exists");
file1.createNewFile()
log.info("file does not exists and created new is "+file1.createNewFile());
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what the problem in my code is?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) it looks like:

> 0 Configuration elements
>
> 1 Pre-Processors
>
> 2 Timers
>
> 3 Sampler
>
> 4 Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
>
> 5 Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
>
> 6 Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

So if you save the file using i.e. [Save responses to a file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/) which is a **Listener** your [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) is executed **before** the file appears.

If this is the case - just change JSR223 Assertion to [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and make sure it's located **below** the Save Responses to a file listener.

Comment: Thanks that worked but in this case how can i put assertion?. I need to validate file in the folder .